# How to clear Facebook Sharer cache?

Tags: facebook, social-networking, hyperlink, social-media

We used the link:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=[shared URL]
```

...to share a particular page. However, Facebook Sharer uses the cached version of the images and the title. Is there a way to quickly clear the Facebook cache or how long do we have to wait until the data gets updated?

I placed `<link rel='image_src' href='[preview image]' />` in between the  tags.

Answer (score 242, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. You could go to this site:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

...then put in the URL of the page you want to share, and click "debug". It will automatically extract all the info on your meta tags and also clear the cache.

Comment: Is there a way to get the same thing but automatically with javascript?
My site have pages that can change often their name. I would like to not wait the 24 hours of Facebook reset of cache, neither i can go on Facebook Lint every time. 
I have tried using an ajax request to Facebook Lint (with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=... as url) but the response is that q value (passed as parameter to above url) is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: @Giovanni Chetelodicoafare, try to use a cron job (linux) or scheduled task (windows) to visit https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fyour-website.com. Cron jobs are available in the admin panel of most hosting providers.

Comment: If you're still having trouble getting it to refresh, try adding a random query string parameter to the end of your URL.

Comment: Just click on the `Fetch new scrape information` button

Comment: I've fetched new scrape information... it see's the right data but the sharer shows old data.  Is there anything else we can do?

Comment: this is not working anymore, even if the data is scraped again. the data in the feeds are still the same

Comment: If you have problem with the image displayed in the share, try to change the image URI.

Comment: Same for me as for Peege151. Debugger shows correct data. Reality sharing still shows cached data. Even if the actual page has no more signs of it (meta etc.) Only thing seems changing the url. Which frankly sucks. Poor Facebook API.

Answer (score 10):

Use api [Is there an API to force Facebook to scrape a page again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100574/is-there-an-api-to-force-facebook-to-scrape-a-page-again)

```
$furl = 'https://graph.facebook.com';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $furl );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
$params = array(
    'id' => '<update_url>',
    'scrape' => true );
$data = http_build_query( $params );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );

curl_exec( $ch );
$httpCode = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
```

Answer (score 10):

> Facebook treats each url as unique and caches the page based on that url, so if you want to share the latest url the simplest solution is to add a query string with the url being shared. In simple words just add ?v=1 at the end of the url. Any number can be used in place of 1.

Hat tip: [Umair Jabbar](http://umairj.com/146/how-to-clear-facebook-shares-cache/)

Comment: I think this will affect the number of links your page has received, since they will be counted for each version, right?

Answer (score 3):

I thing these two links have a wide discussion on your problem related stuff. fb:ref clear cashes by calling

```
fbml.refreshRefUrl
```

like this

```
<tt>fbml.refreshRefUrl("http://www.mysite.com/someurl.php")
```

You can study the related stuff from here [fb:ref](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/ref/). I hope it will work for you

Answer (score 3):

The page to do this is at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and has changed slightly since some of the other answers.

Paste your URL in there and hit "*Debug*". Then hit the "*Fetch new scrape information*" button under the URL text field and you should be all set. It'll pull the fresh meta tags from your page, but they'll still cache so keep in mind you'll need to do this whenever you change them. This is really critical if you are playing with the meta tags to get FB Shared URLs to format the way you want them to inside of facebook.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is intended for developers.

Clearing the cache means that new shares of this webpage will show the new content which is provided in the OG tags. But only if the URL that you are working on has less than 50 interactions (likes + shares). It will also not affect old links to this webpage which have already been posted on Facebook. Only when sharing the URL on Facebook again will the way that Facebook shows the link be updated.

catandmouse's answer is correct but you can also make Facebook clear the OG (OpenGraph) cache by sending a post request to graph.facebook.com (works for both http and https as of the writing of this answer). You do not need an access token.

A post request to graph.facebook.com may look as follows:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: graph.facebook.com
Content-Length: 63
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Mojolicious (Perl)

id=<url_encoded_url>&scrape=true
```

In Perl, you can use the following code where the library Mojo::UserAgent is used to send and receive HTTP requests:

```
sub _clear_og_cache_on_facebook {
    my $fburl     = "http://graph.facebook.com";
    my $ua        = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
    my $clearurl  = <the url you want Facebook to forget>;
    my $post_body = {id => $clearurl, scrape => 'true'};
    my $res       = $ua->post($fburl => form => $post_body)->res;
    my $code      = $res->code;
    unless ($code eq '200') {
        Log->warn("Clearing cached OG data for $clearurl failed with code $code.");
        }
    }
}
```

Sending this post request through the terminal can be done with the following command:

```
curl -F id="<URL>" -F scrape=true graph.facebook.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Append a ?v=random_string to the url.
If you are using this idea with Facebook share, make sure that the og:url param in the response
matches the url you are sharing. This will work with google plus too.

For Facebook, you can also force recrawl by making a post request to https://graph.facebook.com

```
{id: url,
scrape: true}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work posting the above JSON in Postman, but posting a raw text string did cause a refresh: `id=http://www.ridr.me&scrape=true`

Answer (score 1):

I just posted a simple solution that takes 5 seconds here on a related post here - [Facebook debugger: Clear whole site cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420051/facebook-debugger-clear-whole-site-cache/43872413#43872413)

short answer... change your permalinks on a worpdress site in the permalinks settings to a custom one. I just added an underscore.
/_%postname%/
then facebook scrapes them all as new urls, new posts.

Comment: This i simple and cool. Unfortunatelyit leaves unwanted link names.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using wordpress with a cache plugin, make sure you clear all your caches. Also make sure the  image you are using has the recommended facebook size: 1200(w) x 630(h) or 600 x 315.

Answer (score 0):

If you used managed wordpress or caching plugins, you have to CLEAR YOUR CACHE before the facebook debugger tool can fetch new info!

I've been pulling my hair out for weeks figuring out why changes I made wouldn't show up in facebook debugger for 24 hours!!!!   The fix is I have to go into my wordpress dashboard, click the godaddy icon on the top, and click "flush cache."  I think many managed wordpress hosters have a cache to figure out how to clear it and you'll be golden.

Comment: Clearing cache of Wordpress won’t help. At least for me.