# How to refresh Facebook Like Image (clear cache)

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clear Facebook Sharer cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256114/how-to-clear-facebook-sharer-cache)

I've recently changed the image url for my facebook like image.  However, facebook is still picking up the previous image.  Seems like the image has been cached.  I googled the problem and people have suggested running the page through the facebook debugger.  I have done this several times but the new image still isn't showing, despite clicking the like button again.

Here is my iFrame code:

```html
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.org&amp;send=false&amp;layout=box_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=recommend&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=90&amp;appId=1234" 
width="320" height="60"></iframe>
```

Here are my OG tags:

```html
<meta content="123456879" property="fb:app_id"> 
<meta content="sch_donations:donate" property="og:type"> 
<meta content="https://mysite.org/?utm_source=internal&amp;utm_medium=social&amp;utm_content=recommend-on-facebook&amp;utm_campaign=WTH-FB" property="og:url"> 
<meta content="Title text" property="og:title"> 
<meta content="Description text" property="og:description"> 
<meta content="https://mysite.org/image.jpg" property="og:image"> 
<meta content="https://mysite.org/?utm_source=internal&amp;utm_medium=social&amp;utm_content=recommend-on-facebook&amp;utm_campaign=WTH-FB" property="sch_donations:link">
```

Any thoughts on how to force Facebook to clear the cache?

Comment: Have you tried changing the url of the image?

Comment: Yes, I changed the URL of the image then ran my page through the facebook debugger but still the old image displays.

Comment: Have patience, grasshopper. In my experience, it can take at least 12 hours and up to several days before Facebook updates its cache on all its servers. If the correct image displays in the debugger, the process has started. Now all you can do is wait.

Comment: All the articles I'd read made it sound like you ran it through the debugger and 'voila' the cache is cleared! Thanks for the info.

Comment: @littledynamo I am experiencing the same problem as yours. The right image is shown in debugger, but it's not updated in facebook sharer. It has been over 12 hours now. Did this work for your after a certain amount of time?

Comment: @sakibimoon if my memory serves me right, it did change after a couple of days.