# Is there an API to force Facebook to scrape a page again?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, caching, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I'm aware you can force update a page's cache by entering the URL on Facebook's debugger tool while been logged in as admin for that app/page:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

But what I need is a way to **automatically call an API endpoint or something from our internal app whenever somebody from our Sales department updates the main image of one of our pages**. It is not an option to ask thousands of sales people to login as an admin and manually update a page's cache whenever they update one of our item's description or image.

We can't afford to wait 24 hours for Facebook to update its cache because we're getting daily complaints from our clients whenever they don't see a change showing up as soon as we change it on our side.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Page metadata isn't the sort of thing that should change very often, but you can manually clear the cache by going to [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and entering the URL you want to scrape

There's also an API for doing this, which [works for any OG object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/#update):

```
curl -X POST \
     -F "id={object-url OR object-id}" \
     -F "scrape=true" \
     -F "access_token={your access token}" \
     "https://graph.facebook.com"
```

An access_token is now required. This can be an app or page access_token; no user authentication is required.

Comment: It's not that it's changing all the time, but sometimes we need to change an image right before something goes "live" (the URL is already on production, but not seen by the general public before that) and clients get upset if they don't see the new image right away. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Cool, thanks. It is really works and without facebook authentication

Comment: It should work with an App Access Token, so you still don't need any user to authenticate to make this call

Comment: Igy, is there a limit imposed to how many scrapes can be done using the api? In the manual debugger, if I debug back to back, I get an error saying link is blocked -- does the same thing happen with the API?

Comment: Yes, the same rate limits apply in each place as far as I know, it shouldn't cause issues unless you're trying to do it in bulk for many URLs together - in that case, you should spread them out slowly

Comment: @Igy yes that's correct. Any access token will do, but it still needs one :)

Comment: @Igy, I noticed that sometimes Facebook doesn't display the images even though they've been scraped and shown in the debugger: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125241/is-there-a-way-to-force-facebook-to-show-the-ogimage-on-shared-links Why does this happen?

Comment: @steve I'm trying to figure that out too. Got any insight?

Comment: if the first request to fetch the image failed you may see the blank image cached on Facebook's end - try changing the image's URL and rescraping

Comment: It's weird that Facebook doesn't bind the app id as the website's ownership.

Comment: I know that this posts has 3 years old, but I had this problem and this solution doesnt apply anynomre. Someone have a solution for this for api 2.10?

Comment: no, it doesn't work anymore, here is the error log: {"error":{"message":"An access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":104

Comment: Use an access token, any should work, even your app access token should work

Comment: I doesn't seems to work anymore, I've it tried with access_token, but if I post on Facebook, I see the old image.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/url , on the bottom of the page the "Updating" part. Apparently, access_token is no longer required.

Answer (score 15):

If you'd like to do this in PHP in a **with-out waiting for a reply**, the following function will do this:

```
//Provide a URL in $url to empty the OG cache
function clear_open_graph_cache($url, $token) {
  $vars = array('id' => $url, 'scrape' => 'true', 'access_token' => $token);
  $body = http_build_query($vars);

  $fp = fsockopen('ssl://graph.facebook.com', 443);
  fwrite($fp, "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n");
  fwrite($fp, "Host: graph.facebook.com\r\n");
  fwrite($fp, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
  fwrite($fp, "Content-Length: ".strlen($body)."\r\n");
  fwrite($fp, "Connection: close\r\n");
  fwrite($fp, "\r\n");
  fwrite($fp, $body);
  fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: This works :) but you need to send access token as well. So please update your answer.

Comment: @Chittaranjan how to get access token?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the javascript sdk, the version of this you'd want to use is

```
FB.api('https://graph.facebook.com/', 'post', {
            id: [your-updated-or-new-link],
            scrape: true
        }, function(response) {
            //console.log('rescrape!',response);
        });
```

I happen to like promises, so an alternate version using jQuery Deferreds might be

```
function scrapeLink(url){
    var masterdfd = $.Deferred();
    FB.api('https://graph.facebook.com/', 'post', {
        id: [your-updated-or-new-link],
        scrape: true
    }, function(response) {
        if(!response || response.error){
            masterdfd.reject(response);
        }else{
            masterdfd.resolve(response);
        }
    });
    return masterdfd;
}
```

then:

```
scrapeLink([SOME-URL]).done(function(){
    //now the link should be scraped/rescraped and ready to use
});
```

Note that the scraper can take varying amounts of time to complete, so no guarantees that it will be quick.  Nor do I know what Facebook thinks about repeated or automated usages of this method, so it probably pays to be judicious and conservative about using it.

Answer (score 5):

This is a simple ajax implementation. Put this on any page you want facebook to scrape immediately;

```
var url= "your url here";
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com?id='+url+'&scrape=true',
            success: function(data){
               console.log(data);
           }
    });
```

Comment: Yes. It should, but... see @merkushin answer above with the quote from Facebook OG documentation, today it also requires an access_token as a parameter...

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution from within a Drupal node update using curl could be something like this :

```
<?php
function your_module_node_postsave($node) {
    if($node->type == 'your_type') {
        $url = url('node/'.$node->nid,array('absolute' => TRUE));
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/?id='. urlencode($url). '&scrape=true');
        $auth_header = 'Oauth yOUR-ACCESS-TOKEn';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($auth_header));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $r = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
    }
}
```

Notice the hook_node_postsave() implementation which is not standard Drupal core supported.
I had to use [www.drupal.org/project/hook_post_action](http://www.drupal.org/project/hook_post_action) in order to get this facebook scrape pickup last made changes to the node, since hook_node_update() is not triggered after databases have been updated.

Facebook requires now the access token in order to get this done.
Guidelines to acquire a token can be found here :
https://smashballoon.com/custom-facebook-feed/access-token/

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of [Facebook Object Debugger CLI](https://github.com/dedalozzo/facebook-od), a command-line interface written in PHP, aim to refresh the Facebook cache for a single URL or a bunch of URLS using as input a text file. The [package](https://packagist.org/packages/3f/facebook-od) is also available on [Packagist](https://packagist.org) and can be installed using [Composer](http://getcomposer.org).

Answer (score 1):

There are changes in Graph API v2.10:

> When making a GET request against a URL we haven't scraped before, we will also omit the og_object field. To trigger a scrape and populate the og_object, issue a POST /{url}?scrape=true. Once scraped, the og_object will remain cached and returned on all future read requests.
>
> We will require an access token for these requests in all versions of the Graph API beginning October 16, 2017.

Source: [Introducing Graph API v2.10](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/07/18/graph-api-v2.10/)

So now we should use POST-method for scraping:

`POST /{url}?scrape=true`

Not

Answer (score 0):

A solution with the PHP Facebook SDK:

```
<?php
   try {
      $params = [
         'id' => 'https://www.mysitetoscrape.com/page',
         'scrape' => 'true',
      ];
      $response = $fb->post('/', $params);
      print_r($response);
   } catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
   } catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my Ruby solution using Koala gem and Facebook API v2.9

```
    api = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
    response = api.put_object(nil, nil, {scrape: true, id: "url-of-page-to-scrape"})
```

`response` should be a hash of attributes retrieved from the `og:` meta tags on the page which was scraped.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing this same problem.
There is a simple way to clear cache.

1. http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
2. Enter the URL following by **fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING**

Examples: http://www.example.com?fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: That link is already in the question... As long as you own the app you don't need to add `?fbrefresh` or anything. This question is about doing this automatically (in case you want to force a refresh after updating an image, for example, or if you want to force update hundreds or thousands of pages).

Comment: Does this actually work? Is there a facebook source saying this is the case, as it doesn't seem to work for me.