# Facebook share wrong image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We use the Facebook Share option on a website with newsarticles. The website is build with PHP and uses Smarty. We generate a unique URL (stripped like /news/headline-of-the-article) and have the meta properties defined.

When the owner shares a links with an image that was previously uploaded, everything is fine. When he uploads a news image, inserts it into the article and shares, Facebook takes another pictures, the pictures that it finds first on the source-code. Altho, in the preview-box just before you publish, it shows the correct image. Once placed, it's the wrong one.

The Facebook Debug Tool shows as og:image tag > og:image    domain/UserFiles/images/news/standard_14.jpg
But when I look at the RAW tags og:image shows > domain/UserFiles/images/news/bosuil_1.jpg

So the og:image tag does it job and generates the correct URL, but facebook still posts the wrong image. When I force Facebook (manually) to scrape again, it shows everything good and also shares it correct.

I don't get it...

Comment: probably a caching issue. if you are only uploading images in the development stage and they will not change once live, don't worry about it.

Comment: The website is already live for a year and everything worked fine since a few days. I already mailed the hosting to see if they changed something regarding the caching because I know they cache a lot on that website. But maybe somebody knows another solution if the hosting won't cooperate... :)

Comment: bit old but should work... or you should be able to look up any changes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100574/is-there-an-api-to-force-facebook-to-scrape-a-page-again

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found these best practices on facebook's developer wiki: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#precaching

> **Use og:image:width and og:image:height** Open Graph tags
>
> Using these tags will specify the image dimensions to the crawler so that it can
> render the image immediately without having to asynchronously download
> and process it.

After specifying the width and height we have not had a problem with facebook crawling the right picture immediately.