# To publish a post to a Facebook page, I first need to go to the debugger

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

There is an application in Facebook that publishes links to the page. Everything is arranged, the rights are given, the "friendship" of the site and the page is confirmed through 'fb:pages'.

I launch the application (or the same thing in the explorer) and get the answer

> (# 100) Only the owners of the URL have the ability to specify the
>   picture, name, thumbnail or description params.

I'm going to the Facebook object  debugger. The debugger says that there is no information about the page. I say - get it. Gets. I restart the app or return to the explorer and repeat the query - everything is fine.

Why does it decide that I am not the owner of the site without reading the page code on the site? And how would I fix it?

Comment: the link would be important for us, hard to help without that, i´m afraid.

Comment: @luschn What link do you need?  To app? To Facebook  page? To website page?

Comment: to the website. the link you are trying to share, of course.

Comment: Probably,  you about that: `<meta property="fb:pages" content="Page id here" />` It's present, and shown by debugger, and works fine when I restart query after debugger

Comment: @luschn If anybody already shared this page on Facebook, the app works fine. The problem is that Facebook does not catch website page while executing `post page/feed`

Comment: it is important to include all relevant details: the specific url AND your code to post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an API to force Facebook to scrape a page again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100574/is-there-an-api-to-force-facebook-to-scrape-a-page-again)