# facebook share for custom text and image is not working with fb.ui open graph

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to post custom image and text on facebook without meta tag.
here is my working code with app id

```
window.fbAsyncInit=function()
{FB.init({appId:"myappid",autoLogAppEvents:true,xfbml:true,version:"v2.10"});
FB.AppEvents.logPageView()};
(function(e,a,f){
var c,b=e.getElementsByTagName(a)[0];if(e.getElementById(f)){return}c=e.createElement(a);c.id=f;
c.src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";b.parentNode.insertBefore(c,b)}(document,"script","facebook-jssdk"));



   var title =jQuery(".title ").text();
    var discription=jQuery(".imgsrcfb").val();
    var url=jQuery(".url").val();
    var image=jQuery(".image").src();

FB.ui( {
        method:"share_open_graph", action_type:"og.likes", action_properties:JSON.stringify( {
            object: {
                "og:url": url, "og:title": title , "og:description": discription, "og:image": image
            }
        }
        )
    }
    , function(e) {}
    )
```

I have applied all method but none of work
Before they worked.
But in new facebook api upates they just stop working.
Here is my reference site (They also stopped working)
http://drib.tech/programming/dynamically-change-facebook-open-graph-meta-data-javascript

Please help me to shortout this
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Using `method:"share_open_graph"` for this was the last loophole Facebook left open in this regard for a while - and now they closed it. You can not do this any more - the only situation where you can still specify these values dynamically, is when you post to a page you own, and have claimed “ownership” of the domain the content you are sharing is from first.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response.
Can you please let me know Actually what  I have to do for this?
You mean for ownership 
I have to complete varification process ? ( http://prntscr.com/pdbn78 )

Comment: For links that your users share to their own timelines, you can not do this any more at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic OG Tags are not possible anymore, you have to change the OG Tags of the page source if you want to show different information. `share_open_graph` was just a workaround that is deprecated now.

Comment: So is there any method to share my information on facebook?

Comment: yes, by changing the values in the page source of the shared url

Comment: I want to change image on same url
Like post 
share with different image 
Every post have different image
Like 
www.example.com/post1

www.example.com/post2

Comment: different image means you have to use a different url. but that is what you have anyway, right?

Comment: No I want share different images on single URL.
Like here http://prntscr.com/peb0v6
On each square have a share functionality and every sqaure have different image
When we click on square a popup will open with a unique image and test.
So I want to share it with open graph.
So is there any other method ?

Comment: then, you have to use different urls per image. you can just use a parameter though: post1?img=1 and so on - and fill the open graph tags/image depending on the parameter.

Comment: **yes its work** 
But its not working on 1st time when I share image on 2nd time then its working.

Comment: in that case, this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100574/is-there-an-api-to-force-facebook-to-scrape-a-page-again