# Clear all Facebook caced URLs

Tags: facebook, url, caching

I got an idea to clear a cached URL from Facebook on http://4rapiddev.com/facebook-graph-api/clear-facebook-cached-url/ when adding meta tags for sharing on Facebook.

Is there a way to clear all cached URL instead do this step one by one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a cronjob or task scheduler to request to Open Graph URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=<URL>&scrape=true&access_token=<app_access_token>
```

for more information, [Facebook debugger: Clear whole site cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420051/facebook-debugger-clear-whole-site-cache)