# I can't specify the image G+ or Facebook share for my Rails app on Openshift

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openshift, facebook-opengraph, schema.org

I tried using both the snippets for open graph protocol and from schema.org then ran the Structured Data Testing Tool and everything checked out. I restarted my Openshift app but the darn image I specify won't load. It just loads the one displayed on my index page (which is not appropriate)
 The other attributes change but not the image. Any idea what else I should try?

I followed the following but none of it worked
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25581/how-does-google-plus-select-an-image-from-a-shared-link

Comment: Can you provide us some code so that we can try to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Google and Facebook will cache the images for any links you share, so you need to either 1. use different url for testing or 2. find out how to clear the cache for each link.

For example for Facebook you can use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug, see [How to clear Facebook Sharer cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256114/how-to-clear-facebook-sharer-cache)

Comment: @esp4u if that worked please mark the answer as accepted so that other users in the community can benefit from it :) welcome to stackoverflow