# Discrepancy Between Facebook Share Dialog Preivew and What the Dialog Actually Shows

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know what you're thinking.  Facebook has cached the data and it needs to get overwritten.

I have gone to the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776567/facebook-open-graph-not-clearing-cache) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256114/how-to-clear-facebook-sharer-cache) --  where they suggest adding a query string to your URL.  This doesn't really solve my problem though, because the scraper shows the right data...  I notice comments of people that sound like they have my issue, but they aren't really either OP's problem and there's no answers.  For the OP's there, the scraper doesn't show the right information so this actually a different issue.

I've scraped the URL with the debugger a ton.  It shows the right data, the new data I want to see:[image]

Furthermore, the preview that facebook has at the debugger looks perfect.  It looks like this: [image]

But when I open the share dialog on my url, it doesn't show what the preview says it should show.  **At all**. *It still shows the old og:description and og:title.*  The url has updated successfully, however.

My main question is this: **Why is there a discrepancy between facebook's idea of what the share dialog will look like (their preview) and what it actually is, and how can I actually get them to match?**

I'm looking for something more than -- 'facebook's data is cached' because the debugger shows the right information.  It honestly feels like a bug at facebook, but the actual likelihood that I'm doing everything right and facebook isn't is like, near 0.

Comment: For me it currently shows _exactly_ the same in Share dialog preview, as on the debug tool. / Not only caching on Facebook’s end plays a role here, the data might also be locally cached in the user’s browser. (Don’t want to have to fetch the data again each time, if the user should call the Share dialog for the same URL multiple times.)

Comment: You threw together something with my url? Or is this on a different project?  I've considered local cache.  I've cleared all browsing history but that didn't do it.  Would it be stored somewhere else (like favicons), impervious when destroying history?

Comment: I just put the URL your screenshot shows into the debug tool myself, and clicked on the Share dialog preview button from there. / Have you tried a different browser, or a different device and maybe even connection? (In case this is a caching issue on Facebook’s side after all, in combination with device or IP address.)

Comment: No I'm aware of that.  The preview is perfect, but when I actually use a share dialog it uses old data.

Comment: Here’s what I see in debug tool and share dialog preview: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MQzj7.png, and this is what the post looks like on my timeline: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YqBMH.png

Comment: Yeah, there is nothing wrong with the preview.  The issue is on my app, when a user clicks the the share button, the dialog that pops up does NOT match the preview.  The actual dialog is incorrect.